# Concurrent access to static methods which is used to calculate overdue days

Tags: java, concurrency, calendar

I have a static method with the following signature:

```
private static volatile SimpleDateFormat payDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
public static int overdueDays(String repayDay){
    try {
        Date billDate = payDayFormat.parse(repayDay);
        Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.setTime(billDate);
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        long end = endDate.getTimeInMillis();
        long start = startDate.getTimeInMillis();
        Long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Math.abs(end - start));
        return days.intValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error("判断是否逾期解析时间出错");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When there are multiple calls made to the above method concurrently whith the same parameter,the result different.

```
56
56
1279716
56
56
56
5
736387
56
-1226645849
56
```

Only *56* is the right answer. 
But when I replaced **Calendar** with **Joda-Time** ,it returns the right answer.How should I change this code without use **Joda-Time** or **lock**,**unlock** and get the right answer.

Comment: You can mark the method `synchronized`; but you might not need to - are there any static variables used in this method?

Comment: What is the type of `payDayFormat`?

Comment: If you have Java 8, you can use Java Time, (which is pretty much Joda-Time)

Comment: @AndyTurner private static volatile SimpleDateFormat payDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

Comment: Why do you think `payDayFormat` should be `volatile`? I don't think it does what you think...

Comment: marking synchronized is not a good way if you want concurrent programming. Effective java by Joshua Bloch, clearly states the usage of class variables needs to be avoided instead of marking synchronized. If you want to use payDayFormat, either pass it as an argument or create an instance every time.

Comment: @Jango would you expand on the "completely against" remark, please? It's not the approach I'd take, mind you. Are you referring to Item 67 "Avoid excessive synchronization"?

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry i didnt explain in detail. i have edited my comment

Comment: @Jango passing it as an argument doesn't lead to correct behaviour: each thread can still pass the same shared instance.

Comment: @YinbinWang I would just point out that you aren't doing this calculation in the correct way: you are mixing up instants (in milliseconds) and 24-hour long periods (via the date string). You would be much better off doing this in Jodatime (or Java 8), using just `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of sharing `payDayFormat`, which is a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

The reason it works with Jodatime is that its date formatters don't have shared mutable state, because it's sensible.

So, you can either:

- Add `synchronized` to the method signature;
- Add a `synchronized` block just around where you use `payDayFormat`:

  ```
  Date billDate;
  synchronized (payDayFormat) {
    billDate = payDayFormat.parse(repayDay);
  }
  ```
- Create a new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` inside the method;
- Make `payDayFormat` a `ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>`, so that each thread has its own copy.